# Assign diffrent sql scripts for diffrent publish files

Tags: visual-studio-2019, publish, database-project

I got my `database` projects and diffrent p`ublish files` which targets diffrent `databases`. Currently i see there could be only one `sql` marked as `PostDeploy` which simply means this `script` will be executed during publishing. My question is more like can i somehow correlate specific `sql` script to specific `publish file`? My target is to associate specific `sql` to specific `publish` files. Otherwise everytime i need to make sure correct `sql` is marked as `PostDeploy` when executing specific `publish` file

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SQLCMD variables in the project. Set them to the appropriate values to run certain scripts in the post-deploy block.  I wrote up an example here for the idea of a "New" published database bypassing the normal post-deploy scripts. You can see more examples in the post I have on setting permissions by environment.

https://schottsql.com/2013/05/14/ssdt-trick-to-not-run-prepost-sql-on-publish/